# Overlays in columns, vertically centered

Tags: beamer

I'd like to replace some content in beamer `columns` in overlays, and have it still vertically centered (as by default) and, especially, have other content stay fixed. Test case:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{columns}

\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
%\begin{overlayarea}{\linewidth}{8cm}
\begin{block}{}
\only<1>{Foo}
\only<2>{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ultricies mauris in ligula eleifend tincidunt. Etiam in malesuada neque. Curabitur tempus purus purus.}
\end{block}
%\end{overlayarea}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
This line shouldn't move
\end{column}

\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I've found some solutions suggesting the use of `overlayarea`, but that breaks the vertical alignment of the `block` in the page. Is there another solution (which doesn't involve manually specifying all spacing)?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `minipage` to fix vertical alignment with `overlayarea`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{columns}

\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{overlayarea}{\linewidth}{8cm}
\begin{minipage}[c][.85\textheight]{\linewidth}
\begin{block}{}
\only<1>{Foo}
\only<2>{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ultricies mauris in ligula eleifend tincidunt. Etiam in malesuada neque. Curabitur tempus purus purus.}
\end{block}
\end{minipage}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}[c][.85\textheight]{\linewidth}
This line shouldn't move
\end{minipage}
\end{column}

\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```